# Python dynamically generate dependencies between class instances

Tags: python, class, dynamic, graph, dependencies

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
class base(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.last_x = 0.0
  def calc(self, x):
    return x

class A(base):
  def calc(self, x):
    return f_A(x)

class B(base):
  def calc(self, x):
    return f_B(x)

...
```

Each of the lettered classes is basically a wrapper for a corresponding lettered function `f_A`, `f_B`. The class instances include a state variable `self.last_x` as well as the lettered functions are assumed to be state-dependent (i.e. a Markov Chain type process).

What I would like to do is to define dependency chains between instances of these classes in order to try out different functional convolutions. For example, if we wanted to calculate a chain `[a, b]` on a numerical input value `x` we would have to do

```
a = A('firstnode')
b = B('secondnode')

res = b.calc(a.calc(x))
```

The goal is to do this with arbitrarily long chains, while also being able to access results from each intermediate calculation. I.e. if the chain is `[a, b, c]` I would like to make accessible results of `[a]` and `[a, b]` as well (which is why I included a name string for each node in my current implementation).

What would be the right way to setup my classes and data structures for this use case?

So far I have a fairly heavy-handed solution involving multiple dictionaries to keep track of things, but it feels inelegant and I think I might be missing out on something obvious.

Comment: So if you have `[a, b, c]` then you want `res = c.calc(b.calc(a.calc(x)))`?

Comment: And what are `a(x)` and `b(x)` in A and B classes?

Comment: Ah sorry, I see the confusion/my mistake. These are just some generic numerical function depending on `x` (and internal state `self.last_x`). I will change the naming in the question.

Comment: And also what is x in `res = b.calc(a.calc(x))`? is it also a subclass of `base`, or some initial intiger value like, e.g. x= 10?

Comment: One thing you could do is rename `calc()` to `__call__()` then you could write `res = b(a(x))` instead.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Yes, x would be a numeric value. (edited original question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you're improperly reusing names (thus hiding their previous values).  E.g, after:

```
a = A('firstnode')
```

calling `a.calc` will try to call this instance (since the assignment has replaced the fact that previously name `a` was bound to a function) and fail.  Best would be to use more sensible naming.  If for some reason that's not practical, you need to bind the function names internally at class definition time:

```
class A(base):
    def calc(self, x, a=a):
        return a(x)
```

where the `a=a` does the trick, and so forth.

Having passed that hurdle, the second one is that you want the last result of each class to be saved, but, you don't save it.  So, change the code to e.g

```
class A(base):
    def calc(self, x, a=a):
        self.last_result = a(x)
        return self.last_result
```

Once that is done, performing your desired operation on a list of class instances is the least of your problems.  E.g

```
def doit(instances, x):
    curr = x
    for inst in instances: curr=inst.calc(curr)
    return curr
```

and after this

```
[inst.last_result for inst in instances]
```

will give you the intermediate results you're looking for.